# What type of doors can a hacked Akuma drone breach?

Tags: invisible-inc

I noticed that hacked Akuma drones have a "Break Door" ability that costs 1 AP, which I assume allows them (and you) to break down closed doors with them.

What types of doors can be destroyed with an Akuma drone? Does it only work on regular unlocked doors, or can it also be used to break through locked level 1 red doors, or even locked vault doors?